# pandas sort dataframe by a series, using a combination of numbers and letters

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sort a dataframe by one column, which includes a combination of numbers and letters.

```
df = [{"user": "seth",
       "name": "1"},
     {"user" : "chris",
       "name": "10A"},
     {"user" : "aaron",
       "name": "4B"},
     {"user" : "dan",
       "name": "10B"}]
```

My code:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['name'])
```

This gets me:

```
df1 = [{"user": "seth",
       "name": "1"},
     {"user" : "chris",
       "name": "10A"},
     {"user" : "dan",
       "name": "10B"},
     {"user" : "aaron",
       "name": "4B"}]
```

I want:

```
df1 =    [{"user": "seth",
           "name": "1"},
         {"user" : "aaron",
           "name": "4B"},
         {"user" : "chris",
           "name": "10A"},
         {"user" : "dan",
           "name": "10B"}]
```

Edit:

It was flagged as a similar question, and their code:

```
   DPRexitPoints.reindex(index=natsorted(DPRexitPoints.PageName))
```

It returns a sorted dataframe, but all values have been replaced by NaNs.

Comment: Is this dict or pandas dataframe or list ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S it is a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `np.argsort` and `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[np.argsort(df['name'].str
                      .extract('^(\d*)')[0]
                      .astype(int))
       ]
```

Output:

```
    user name
0   seth    1
2  aaron   4B
1  chris  10A
3    dan  10B
```

Comment: hmmm, it sorting by numbers only, not by combinations of numbers and letters. Possible solution should be extract both and the sorting or use `natural sort`

Comment: It gives me this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''